# Angular2 TemplateRef Selector

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template

In my [datatable project](https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table), developers have the ability to declare templates in the table declaration to be used for the header cell and the body cell.

```
<datatable>
    <datatable-column name="Name">
        <template let-column="column">
            Header: {{column.name}}
        </template>
        <template let-value="value">
            Hi: <strong>{{value}}</strong>
        </template>
    </datatable-column>
    <datatable-column name="Age">
        <datatable-body-template let-value="value">
            I'm: <strong>{{value}}</strong> old
        </datatable-body-template>
    </datatable-column>
</datatable>
```

in the above example, the first template is the header cell template and the second one is the body cell template and the order matters. If you only declare one template, it will only do body cell template. You can see how this is being done currently [here](https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table/blob/master/src/components/column.directive.ts#L23).

I do currently allow you to pass `TemplateRef`s via a `Input` to the column directive but that approach is ok but as an API consumer, the declarative templates inside the component definition is a cleaner approach.

Its also worth noting, that its not possible to do naming via something like `#body` and `#header` since you can have multiple columns making the names not unique.

This DSL is not very intuitive because its not very explicit which is which and it depends on order. `ng-content` allows you to put in a selector attribute, I was wondering what the best way to accomplish something like that with templates would be? So something like:

```
<datatable>
    <datatable-column name="Name">
        <datatable-header-template let-column="column">
            Header: {{column.name}}
        </datatable-header-template>
        <datatable-body-template let-value="value">
            Hi: <strong>{{value}}</strong>
        </datatable-body-template>
    </datatable-column>
</datatable>
```

I was digging around trying to see if its possible to override the `TemplateRef` but I'm not sure thats even a good idea.

So with all that said... my question, how can i accomplish named selector template refs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the templates to inputs

```
<template #header let-column="column">
    Header: {{column.name}}
</template>

<template #body let-value="value">
    Hi: <strong>{{value}}</strong>
</template>

<datatable>
    <datatable-column name="Name" [header]="header" [column]="body"></datatable-column>
</datatable>
```

**update**

It is also possible to add template variables and query by these

```
<datatable>
  <template let-column="column" #header>
    header1
  </template>
  <template let-value="value" #column>
    column1
  </template>

  <template let-value="value" #column>
    column2
  </template>
```

```
  @ContentChildren('header', {read: TemplateRef}) headerTemplates:QueryList<TemplateRef>;
  @ContentChildren('column', {read: TemplateRef}) columnTemplates:QueryList<TemplateRef>;
```

or use directives. This approach allows to pass additional information

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[header]';
})
class HeaderTemplate {
  constructor(private template:TemplateRef) {};

  @Input() header:String;
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[column]';
})
class ColumnTemplate {
  constructor(private template:TemplateRef) {};

  @Input() column:String;
}
```

```
<datatable>
  <template let-column="column" header="1">
    header1
  </template>
  <template let-value="value" column="1">
    column1
  </template>

  <template let-value="value" column="2">
    column2
  </template>

</datatable>
```

```
@ContentChildren(HeaderTemplate) headerTemplates:QueryList<HeaderTemplate>;
@ContentChildren(ColumnTemplate) columnTemplates:QueryList<ColumnTemplate>;
```

the properties `template` and `header` / `column` of `headerTemplate` / `columnTemplate` allow you to access the template and a passed value (can have additional `@Inputs()` but one that matches the selector is easiest to use).

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/twBQ9Zdw0u1xz1ogORKu?p=preview)

Comment: Ah yes, I currently allow that but its not very clean as a api consumer in my opinion. Also, it gets even messier if you want multiple custom templates for each column. I'll update the demo to show that.

Comment: Just a side note, Günter you are a beast! Good chance to become the Jon Skeet of Angular 2 here on Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: After I saw https://toggl.com/programming-princess, I knew I have to become #1 on SO to get mentioned this way as well :D

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - i updated the example to show this.

Comment: I don't get the "multiple custom templates for each column." I saw you updated the question but I don't see there multiple templates passed to a column. (To my original approach - you can also use `[column]="[body1, body2, body3]" to pass multiple templates)

Comment: How do you access the templates?

Comment: This is how I'm doing it currently - https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table/blob/master/src/components/column.directive.ts#L23

Comment: Ya, your approach will work, and I do offer that capability but thats not really  what I'm after for the api.

Comment: Another approach is to add template variables `<template #column>...</template>` and query for `@ContentChildren('column', {read: TemplateRef}) column : QueryList<TemplateRef>`.

Comment: Don't those have to be unqiue though?

Comment: I suppose that fixes the issue, not very intuitive though. Wanna update your answer and i will mark as answer.

Comment: You can also use directives. This plunker shows both attempts https://plnkr.co/edit/twBQ9Zdw0u1xz1ogORKu?p=info

Comment: Update my answer.

Comment: Thanks again @GünterZöchbauer - I applied ur suggestion and works nice! https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table/blob/2.1.3/src/components/columns/column.directive.ts#L25

Comment: Glad to hear :) Thanks for the feedback.